# compute aggregated mean with group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have a dataframe data like this:

```
Cluster VolumePred      ConversionPred
0   0-3     8.0          7.0
1   0-3     175.0       85.0
2   0-3     17           4.0
3   4-6     14           4.0
4   7-9     29.0        19.0
```

And I need to add a column "meanKPI" which is equal to the sum of "ConversionPred" divided by the sum of "VolumePred" grouped by "Cluster.

I tried with this:

```
def KPI_Pred_mean(x, y):
    #print (x)
    return (x.sum()/y.sum())
    
    #data.ConversionPred.sum()/sum_vol_pred
    
df3=data.groupby(['Cluster'])['ConversionPred', 'VolumePred'].apply(KPI_Pred_mean).reset_index()
```

But I got an error:

> TypeError: KPI_Pred_mean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the desired output, exactly? And what do you think is passed as `x` and `y` into `KPI_Pred_mean` when you apply the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KPI_Pred_mean` is expecting two arguments, the way you are giving the function as a lambda to `apply` can be rewritten as: `.apply(lambda x: KPI_Pred_mean(x)`. Meaning it's missing the `y` variable. You can rewrite your code in two ways:

#### 1 - rewrite lambda

```
df3=data.groupby(['Cluster'])['ConversionPred', 'VolumePred'].apply(lambda x: KPI_Pred_mean(x["ConversionPred"], x["volumePred"]).reset_index(name = 'KPI_Pred_mean')
```

#### 2 - rewrite your function

```
def KPI_Pred_mean(row):
    return (row["ConversionPred"].sum()/row["volumePred"].sum())
```

Number 1 is probably better since it keeps your function nice and generic.

Comment: The solutions above wotks but they give 0 as a name of the new calculated column.. How to change it to KPI_Pred_mean ? thanks

Comment: Updated my answer (same as BENY)

Comment: @BENY it works!! thank you so much !

Comment: it works!! thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Change your call `apply` self-def function to

```
out = df.groupby(['Cluster']).apply(lambda x : KPI_Pred_mean(x['ConversionPred'],x['VolumePred'])) .reset_index(name = 'KPI_Pred_mean') 
Out[267]: 
  Cluster  KPI_Pred_mean
0     0-3       0.480000
1     4-6       0.285714
2     7-9       0.655172
```

Comment: I didn't time it but `sums = df.groupby('Cluster').sum(); result = sums['VolumePred']/sums['ConversionPred']` should be faster by avoiding to apply a pure python function.

Comment: @BENY  thank you for your response, How to rename the column "0" to "KPI_Pred_mean"?

Comment: @buddy change to .reset_index(name = 'KPI_Pred_mean')